# jquery change text according to id

Tags: jquery

I am new using jQuery..

I have a list something like this

```
<ul id="abc">
<li><a id="sp">test</a></li>
<li><a id="sb">test2</a></li>
</ul>
```

How do i change text according to id

i tried something like this

```
    $("#abc li").click(function() {
        if($("#abc li a").attr('id') == 'sp')
            alert(111111);
    });
```

the alert never popped up.

What could be wrong here

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   $("#abc li").click(function() {
        if($('a', this).get(0).id == 'sp')
            alert(111111);
    });
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/PeMQm/

Comment: it gets the 1st DOM element, its better than doing `$('a', this).attr('id')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#abc li").click(function() {
    if($("#abc li a").attr('id') == 'sp')
        alert(111111);
});
```

should work http://jsfiddle.net/eTFR5/1/

and works same as

```
$("#abc li").click(function() {
    if($('a', this).get(0).id == 'sp')
        alert(111111);
});
```

according to jquery docs

> The .attr() method gets the attribute value for only the first element in the matched set.

And for your Question

> How do i change text according to id

```
$("#abc li").click(function() {
    $("#sp").text("whatever you like");
});
```

Comment: HAhahahahahahahahh Someone have a good sense of humor! MEGAlol

Comment: That is very untrue. the OP's code does not work. did you try it?

Comment: I have given the link http://jsfiddle.net/eTFR5/1/ and does the answer seem clear enough for you?

Comment: Yes! @TheSuperTramp I understood well your first posted answer! You did nothing wrong... almost. You answered well but just literally! fun fun fun +1! jhehehe now you're back to '0' :D gehehehe Just genial, this makes me lough so much that i'm still in the good mood :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a *particular* reason for wanting to click the list item itself, rather than the links, put the click handler on the `<a>` tags, like this:

```
$('#abc a').click(function() {
    if (this.id === 'sp') {
        alert(this.id);
    }
    return false;
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/bZsrg/